# android как измерить скорость по акселерометру

Tags: android

Здравствутйе. Как я могу измерить скорость по акселерометру? Хочу попробовать измерять скорость, но начать с простого, хотя бы попробовать измерить ее по осям.

```
    // наносекунда в секундах
    private static final float NS2S = 1.0f / 1000000000.0f;

    long prevTime = 0; // время прошлого "прихода" данных     
    long currTime = 0; // время "прихода" текущих данных

    float prevAx; // ускорение по X при прошлом измерении
    float prevAy; // ускорение по Y при прошлом измерении
    float prevAz; // ускорение по Z при прошлом измерении

    float currAx; // ускорение по X при текущем измерении
    float currAy; // ускорение по Y при текущем измерении
    float currAz; // ускорение по Z при текущем измерении

    float vx;  // текущая скорость по X
    float vy;  // текущая скорость по Y
    float vz;  // текущая скорость по Z

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
            currAx = event.values[0];
            currAy = event.values[1];
            currAz = event.values[2];

            if (prevTime == 0) {
                prevTime = event.timestamp;
                prevAx = currAx;
                prevAy = currAy;
                prevAz = currAz;
                return;
            }

            float dAx = currAx - prevAx;  // изменение ускорений между прошлым и текущим измерением по X
            float dAy = currAy - prevAy;  // изменение ускорений между прошлым и текущим измерением по Y
            float dAz = currAz - prevAz;  // изменение ускорений между прошлым и текущим измерением по Z

            final float dT = (event.timestamp - prevTime) * NS2S;  // время между прошлым и текущим измерением по времени.

            float vx0 = dAx * dT;    // прибавка к скорости со времни прошлого измерения по X
            float vy0 = dAy * dT;    // прибавка к скорости со времни прошлого измерения по Y
            float vz0 = dAz * dT;    // прибавка к скорости со времни прошлого измерения по Z

            vx += vx0;     // Общая скорость по X
            vy += vy0;     // Общая скорость по Y
            vz += vz0;     // Общая скорость по Z

            printAcc(vx, vy, vz);  // вывожу значения на экран

            // делаю текущие значения прошлыми.
            prevTime = currTime;
            prevAx = currAx;
            prevAy = currAy;
            prevAz = currAz;
        }
    }
```

Хочу при движении с телефоном , увидеть примерно следующее:
скорость по оси x = 2 м/c  по оси z = 3 м/c. Но, получается какая-то чушь.

Comment: Это многократно обсуждалось на Stack overflow,  не измерите потому что акселерометр ловит кучу  случайных хаотичных движений вашего организма))

Answer (score 1):

Многократно обсуждалось на StackOverflow ([здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264518/using-accelerometer-gyroscope-and-compass-to-calculate-devices-movement-in-3d) например) и Google разжевывал ([здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k) например, 23-я минута).
Акселерометр и/или гироскоп не предназначен для длительных непрерывных измерений. Не забывайте, что в телефоне установлен датчик стоимостью от $2 до $10, и максимум, что можно сделать на его показаниях - обеспечить реакцию на сиюминутное движение - наклон, рывок и т.д.

Даже в самолётах, где установлены инерционные системы стоимостью несколько сотен тыс убитых енотов, такие способы вычисления скорости и пройденного расстояния не применяются.

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокод:

```
t=1; //период опроса датчика в секуднах
v=0; //начальная скорость в м/с
a=0; //начальное ускорение в м/с^2
while(a=getCurrentAcceleration()){
    v += a*t;
    wait(t);
}
```

Но, боюсь, как не уменьшай период опроса - реальная скорость от расчитанной будет отличаться чем дальше - тем больше.

Если супер точность не нужна, то имеет смысл использовать GPS (там высота тоже определяется, да)